# Install mysql module for python with pip

Tags: python, mysql, pip, python-3.6

I'm trying to install mysql module for python with pip, but I got an error:

```
mysqlclient.lib(typelib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
mysqlclient.lib(viosslfactories.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
mysqlclient.lib(my_winfile.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol__iob_func
mysqlclient.lib(my_messnc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
mysqlclient.lib(client.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
mysqlclient.lib(my_thr_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
mysqlclient.lib(default.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\_mysql.cp36-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

Answer (score 0):

in windows use [python unofficial binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) to install MySQL. use this link and download your requirement python package.

install it using,

```
pip install ~/Downloads/mysqlclient‑1.3.10‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

from that link search **mysql** or **mysqlclient‑1.3.10‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl** download and install using same pip

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient==1.3.10 from file:///D:/Downloads/mysqlclient-1.3.10-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl in c:\python36\lib\site-packages

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error this fixed it for me.

```
pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient
```